# CSS div width - lining divs... widths seem to be off in IE7

Tags: html, vb.net, html-table, internet-explorer-7

So far, I'm doing this programmatically using VB.net/ASP.net:

```
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" style="border-
           width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:12px;">
    <tr>
 <td colspan="6"></td>
      <td align="center" colspan="3" style="background-color:#F0D3D3;text-
          decoration:underline;">SET</td>
      <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#CFF5CE;"></td>
      <td align="center" colspan="3" style="background-color:#BEE0F7;text-
          decoration:underline;">REM</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
<th style="width:70px;">M</th>
     <th style="width:70px;">PG</th>
     <th style="width:70px;">PV</th>
     <th style="width:70px;">PDD</th>
     <th style="width:40px;">R</th>
     <th style="width:55px;">I #</th>
     <th style="background-color:#F0D3D3;width:70px;">P A</th>
     <th style="background-color:#F0D3D3;width:70px;">U D</th>
     <th style="background-color:#F0D3D3;width:70px;">B P</th>
     <th style="background-color:#CFF5CE;width:70px;">P U</th>
     <th style="background-color:#CFF5CE;width:70px;">D E</th>
     <th style="background-color:#BEE0F7;width:70px;">P</th>
     <th style="background-color:#BEE0F7;width:70px;">U D</th>
     <th style="background-color:#BEE0F7;width:70px;">B P</th>
    </tr>
</table>

<div style="width:100%;clear:both;text-align:left;margin:0;">
   <div style="width:375px;float:left;margin:0;display:block;">
    <img onclick="change(this.parent);" src="minus99.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
    <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">Test Company</span>
   </div>
   <div style="background-
        color:#F0D3D3;width:210px;float:left;margin:0;display:block;"></div>
   <div style="background-
        color:#CFF5CE;width:140px;float:left;margin:0;display:block;"></div>
   <div style="background-
        color:#BEE0F7;width:210px;float:right;padding:0;margin:0;display:block;"></div>
</div>
```

This should give me four DIVS inside a container DIV. Here's what it's coming out as:

[image]

The correct blocks above the non-inline blocks are from a table with the same exact widths as the ones I'm using on the Divs. There isn't any CSS adding pixels to them, I don't think. I need to line these up, and I can't figure out where my problem is here.

Comment: Instead of posting the VB code, can you post the HTML/CSS that is generated?  That way, us non-VB folks can take a crack at the question.

Comment: There ya go... Should be in HTML now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Width: 100%` on the table overrides individual column widths. In your table, there are 13 `<th>`, and each will have a width of 1/13:th of the table's width. A `width` property on a `<th>` doesn't do anything. You could force it by adding `display: inline-block` to the `<th>`, but I wouldn't want to go that way.

Also, you should set the pink and green divs to `float: right` in order to remove the white inbetween green and blue (note however that you'll have to change the order of the divs in your code).

Also, I'd suggest using a table instead if you're aiming to present tabular data.

Comment: Floating all the DIVs right with the exception of my NAME div at least lines them up... but why are the pixel widths of those boxes so unbelievably off from the header cells when they are the same widths?

Comment: Expanded my answer to explain why the width's aren't the same.

Comment: Learn something new everyday... hmmmm.

Comment: @jlrolin: the `width: 100%` on the table is stretching the ths/tds proportionally to make them total the table's width. So, almost as nemetroid said: they keep their relative width, but stretch to fill the whole width of the table. You can get the same effect if you use percent for the child-div widths, instead of a pixel value - then they'll stretch.

Comment: @jlrolin: but it seems you want to present tabular data - if so, I second nemetroid's suggestion to keep with tables.

Answer (score 1):

You can use instead of divs the `colspan="[number]"`, for example:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" border="0" style="border-width:0px;width:100%;border-collapse:collapse;font-size:12px;">
<tr>
     <td colspan="6"></td>
     <td align="center" colspan="3" style="background-color:#F0D3D3;text-decoration:underline;">SET</td>
     <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#CFF5CE;"></td>
     <td align="center" colspan="3" style="background-color:#BEE0F7;text-decoration:underline;">REM</td>
</tr>
<tr>
     <th style="width:70px;">M</th>
     <th style="width:70px;">PG</th>
     <th style="width:70px;">PV</th>
     <th style="width:70px;">PDD</th>
     <th style="width:40px;">R</th>
     <th style="width:55px;">I #</th>
     <th style="background-color:#F0D3D3;width:70px;">P A</th>
     <th style="background-color:#F0D3D3;width:70px;">U D</th>
     <th style="background-color:#F0D3D3;width:70px;">B P</th>
     <th style="background-color:#CFF5CE;width:70px;">P U</th>
     <th style="background-color:#CFF5CE;width:70px;">D E</th>
     <th style="background-color:#BEE0F7;width:70px;">P</th>
     <th style="background-color:#BEE0F7;width:70px;">U D</th>
     <th style="background-color:#BEE0F7;width:70px;">B P</th>
</tr>
<tr>
     <td colspan="6">
          <img onclick="change(this.parent);" src="minus99.jpg" style="border-width:0px;" />
          <span style="font-weight:bold;font-size:16px;">Test Company</span>
     </td>
     <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#F0D3D3;"></td>
     <td colspan="2" style="background-color:#CFF5CE;"></td>
     <td colspan="3" style="background-color:#BEE0F7;"></td>
</tr> 
</table>
```

Hoped i helped you.. =)

Comment: Understood, but we want to try to use DIVs as a CSS layout only. I will likely need to adapt the actual table and headers to CSS later as well.

Answer (score 0):

Did you `put cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"` on the table? If not, that might be where the difference is coming from.
Or maybe border.

Can you include the table header?

Comment: Added it to the overall post above. Cellpadding is 4, but making it zero doesn't make a difference. No border.